# How to restrict user from doing su to another user apart from root

Tags: linux, sudo, root

I am have enabled sudo access to one of the user, Now if he wants to become root he can sudo su - but at the sametime i want to make sure he should not be able to su to appprd and apptest users.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The root user is able to do *anything*, including changing the root password and/or editing the `sudoers` file to lock you out.

Instead of giving full super-user powers to a user, why not give him access to a more restrictive set of commands that he needs to run as root?

See the `sudoers` manual on your system.

Comment: When allowing commands, only allow commands that don't provide a sub-shell.  Use the principle of giving users the least privileges required to do their job.  If the need full root access, you need to trust them.

Comment: Thanks Bill i'll restrict users to sudo specific commands only